# Bootstrap4- collapsing paragraph using checkbox

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In the following code Bootstrap4 has strange behavior

```css
.form-group .custom-control{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
<div class="form-group row has-success">
   <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input id="father_dead_or_alive" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#father_message">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
   </label>
<p id="father_message" class="collapse form-text text-muted">BBBBBBBBBBBBB</p>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

When checking the box, the check sign is not displaying!
How can I fix this?

Comment: It appears that the problem is in the jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move:

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#father_message"`

... from input to the `description` span.

Comment: Yeah the OP can try a lot of other things too. It's not about trying, it's about giving an answer.

Comment: @MuhammadMousa I tried that. The toggle didn't work! Can you run your idea on snippet